# Python execute complex shell command

Tags: python

Hi I have to execute a shell command :diff <(ssh -n root@10.22.254.34 cat /vms/cloudburst.qcow2.*) <(ssh -n root@10.22.254.101 cat /vms/cloudburst.qcow2)
I tried

```
cmd="diff <(ssh -n root@10.22.254.34 cat /vms/cloudburst.qcow2.*) <(ssh -n root@10.22.254.101 cat /vms/cloudburst.qcow2)"
args = shlex.split(cmd)
output,error = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr= subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

However I am getting an error diff: extra operand cat

I am pretty new to python. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You are passing the parameters "<(ssh", "-n", "root@...", "cat" literally to the diff tool. When typing in a shell, the "<(...)" parts get evaluated first, and the resulting (file) is passed to the diff command as parameter instead. What shell are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `<(...)` (process substitution) syntax, which is interpreted by the shell.  Provide `shell=True` to Popen to get it to use a shell:

```
cmd = "diff <(ssh -n root@10.22.254.34 cat /vms/cloudburst.qcow2.*) <(ssh -n root@10.22.254.101 cat /vms/cloudburst.qcow2)"
output,error = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, executable="/bin/bash", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

Since you don't want the Bourne shell (/bin/sh), use the executable argument to determine the shell to use.

Comment: I tried that, however I am getting an error '/bin/sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected'.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a special syntax called process substitiution in your command line. This is supported by most modern shells (bash, zsh), but not by /bin/sh. Therefore, the method suggested by Ned might not work. (It could, if another shell provides /bin/sh and does not "correctly emulate" sh's behaviour, but it is not guaranteed to).
try this instead:

```
cmd = "diff <(ssh -n root@10.22.254.34 cat /vms/cloudburst.qcow2.*) <(ssh -n root@10.22.254.101 cat /vms/cloudburst.qcow2)"
output,error = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

This is basically what the shell=True parameter does, but with /bin/bash instead of /bin/sh (as described in the [subprocess docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)).

Comment: perfect! simple, effective